# AUTOSAR Quality of service goals

Tags: qos

I am carrying out a research on the QoS mechanisms in AUTOSAR. Can any one please let me know on which OSI layer AUTOSAR resides on?

Answer (score 0):

The AUTOSAR Application Layer resides on OSI layer 7 (*Application Layer*). However, certain parts that are used for communication also reach down to the *Presentation Layer*.

[image: AUTOSAR v4.0 architecture]